# Animate textblock on stackpanel mouseover in WPF

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml

Have a look at the XAML below.

I want the «HelloText» TextBlock to "glow" when I hover over it with the mouse (thus the storyboard instead of a trigger on IsMouseOver). The code below doesn't work since two TextBlocks have the same name. How can I edit this code so that I can apply «MyStackPanelStyle» to more than one StackPanel?

```
<Window.Resources>
  <Style TargetType="StackPanel" x:Key="MyStackPanelStyle">
    <Style.Triggers>
      <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="StackPanel.MouseEnter">
        <BeginStoryboard>
          <Storyboard>
            <ColorAnimation Duration="0:0:0.5" Storeboard.TargetName="HelloText" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" To="LightGray" />
          </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
      </EventTrigger>
      <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="StackPanel.MouseLeave">
        <BeginStoryboard>
          <Storyboard>
            <ColorAnimation Duration="0:0:0.5" Storeboard.TargetName="HelloText" Storyboard.Target="TextBlock" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" To="#505050" />
          </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
      </EventTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
  </Style>
</Window.Resources>

<StackPanel style="MyStackPanelStyle">
  <TextBlock Name="HelloText" Text="Hello" />
  <TextBlock Text="World" />
</StackPanel>

<StackPanel style="MyStackPanelStyle">
  <TextBlock Name="HelloText" Text="Hello" />
  <TextBlock Text="World" />
</StackPanel>
```

**Edit:**

I've read an [article by Sergio Loscialo](http://www.wintellect.com/CS/blogs/sloscialo/archive/2009/08/06/wpf-animating-multiple-elements-simultaneously.aspx) which lookded promising. Unfortunately, this solution applies to all target elements that inherit from AnimationPlaceholder, which means that it won't work when I've more than one of these StackPanels on my page.

Comment: Since Foreground is inherited, you could just animate that on the StackPanel and your TextBlocks should animate as a result. However, any other controls in your StackPanel will also have their Foreground animated.

Comment: @KentBoogaart thanks for your answer, but the animation should only apply to a defined TextBlock in the StackPanel

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I want the «HelloText» TextBlock to "glow" when I hover over it with
>   the mouse

Sounds likes you want to be providing a `Style` for the `TextBlock` and not the `StackPanel`:

```
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock" x:Key="GlowingTextBlockStyle">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="UIElement.MouseEnter">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ColorAnimation Duration="0:0:0.5" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground.Color" To="LightGray" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="UIElement.MouseLeave">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ColorAnimation Duration="0:0:0.5" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground.Color" To="#505050" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </StackPanel.Resources>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="Hello" Style="{StaticResource GlowingTextBlockStyle}" />
        <TextBlock Text="World" />
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="Hello" Style="{StaticResource GlowingTextBlockStyle}" />
        <TextBlock Text="World" />
    </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

> when I hover over it with the mouse (thus the storyboard instead of a
>   trigger on IsMouseOver).

Please note the same effect can be achieved with `IsMouseOver` by setting the `EnterActions` and `ExitActions`:

```
    <StackPanel>
        <StackPanel.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="TextBlock" x:Key="GlowingTextBlockStyle">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Trigger.EnterActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimation Duration="0:0:0.5" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground.Color" To="LightGray" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </Trigger.EnterActions>
                        <Trigger.ExitActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimation Duration="0:0:0.5" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground.Color" To="#505050" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </Trigger.ExitActions>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </StackPanel.Resources>
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="Hello" Style="{StaticResource GlowingTextBlockStyle}" />
            <TextBlock Text="World" />
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="Hello" Style="{StaticResource GlowingTextBlockStyle}" />
            <TextBlock Text="World" />
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

The above answer assumes you don't have a requirement which relates the `TextBlock` to your `StackPanel` (e.g. always animate the first `TextBlock` in the `StackPanel`, or always animate a `TextBlock` with a certain name). If this was the case, relying on the `Name` would be brittle and you would be better off creating a custom control or user control with a property or named part for the special content.

**Edit:**

To start the animations when the mouse enters the `StackPanel` you could just adapt the above solution to use a `DataTrigger` instead:

```
<Style TargetType="TextBlock" x:Key="GlowingTextBlockStyle">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Panel}}, Path=IsMouseOver}" Value="True">
            <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ColorAnimation Duration="0:0:0.5" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground.Color" To="LightGray" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
            <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ColorAnimation Duration="0:0:0.5" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground.Color" To="#505050" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you. I assume your solution only works when I hover over the TextBlock, not the StackPanel. So if I've a huge StackPanel that contains a tiny TextBlock in the upper left corner, then this won't be the right solution either.

Comment: The additional info after the edit made it work the way I wanted. Thank you very much!